Understanding the components of backlight circuit of digital watch
I am not a hardware engineer. I studied basic electronics 15 years back in school days, so you can consider me a noob.
I have a digital watch in which all the features (time, alarm, chime, etc) work fine, except the backlight. This watch is just 2 years old. I opened the watch and the internals were very clean, no sign of rust, etc. Now, the button that's responsible for glowing backlight should also have proper contact because when there is an alarm, pressing the light button stops it, so I assume the button is fine. I don't think the EL panel has gone bad because the EL was rarely used in last 2 years. So I first want to start confirming that the components in EL circuit are fine.
Just by looking at the watch, I definitely can't guess what makes the EL circuit but I am starting with the button for backlight and following the trails. I can identify few SMD components like diodes, quartz and resistors, but there are some which I am not able to.
Below are the front and back screenshots


Below are some closeups where I suspect the EL circuit component lie :


Questions :

What is this component that looks like a red tube? That's also black from one corner. I suspect it. Can this be tested by a multimeter?
What's the best way to verify the EL circuit is fine? Is my idea of verifying each component with multimeter fine? (I am not sure if all the components can be verified with a multimeter).

I do have a basic multimeter with me.
EDIT
I watched couple of videos on youtube and started analyzing the EL circuit (the last picture). Out of three resistors, one reads 10K and other two read 1K each on multimeter. I tested the two transistors as well and the continuity difference between Base-Collector and Base-emmitter is 6 for both of these. There is a capacitor as well and it reads 741 on one side and nothing on the other (using continuity). As per my noob knowledge, all looks ok. Please correct me.
The red tube like component looks to be a zener diode (just guessing) and testing using continuity on multimeter reads 572 on one direction and nothing on the other.
If I flip the circuit board, on the back, there is a drum like component that has copper wire coils, like transformer. If you notice, there are two of these. Using continuity, one dum reads 69 and other reads 152 (either direction).

The two drums are coils, they shouldn’t be damaged since it’s just ferrite and few turns of copper.
The red component is diode, maybe a zener but more probably a signal diode 1n4148 or similar. Reading 0.6 in one direction with multimeter is ok.
I would check the button contact as first, btw. (Oxidation, physically damage because of excessive pressing, or contact surface damage because of arc - a current could melt the surfaces).
